# Prove if a series $\sum{a_n}$ is convergent, then $b_n = \frac{1}{a_{n+1}} - \frac{1}{a_n}$ is unbounded

Tags: sequences-and-series

Let $(a_n)_{n \geq 1}$ be a decreasing sequence of positive reals. Let $s_n = a_1 + a_2 + ... + a_n$ and

\begin{align}
b_n = \frac{1}{a_{n+1}} - \frac{1}{a_n}, n \geq 1
\end{align}

Prove that if $(s_n)_{n \geq 1}$ is convergent, then $(b_n)_{n \geq 1}$ is unbounded.

My attempt: If $\lim_{n \to \infty} \frac{a_{n+1}}{a_n} \neq 1 $ or DNE, then we can bound $\frac{a_{n+1}}{a_{n}}$ by $\frac{a_{n+1}}{a_{n}} < \frac{1}{k}$ for some $ k>1$

Hence $b_n = \frac{1}{a_{n+1}} - \frac{1}{a_n} > \frac{k-1}{a_n} \to \infty$

On the other hand, if $\lim_{n \to \infty} \frac{a_{n+1}}{a_n} = 1$ I'm not sure how to prove for this case.

I tried $\forall \epsilon >0 , \exists N>0, n>N \implies |\frac{a_{n+1}}{a_n} - 1| < \epsilon \implies |\frac{1}{a_{n+1}} - \frac{1}{a_n}| < \frac{\epsilon}{1-\epsilon} \frac{1}{a_n}$.

But this doesn't help me as I am looking for a lower bound.

Any hints are appreciated

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hint: Suppose for the sake of contradiction that the $b_n$ were bounded.  Then show that $\sum{a_n}$ is divergent.

Comment: thanks, I got it

Comment: A detailed version of this answer has already been posted, so here is another, which is simpler. Suppose there is $B > 0$ such that $1/a_{n+1} - 1/a_n \leqslant B$ for all $n.$ Then $1/a_{n+1} - 1/a_1 \leqslant Bn$ for all $n.$ Therefore $1/a_{n+1} \leqslant 2Bn$ for all $n \geqslant 1/(a_1B).$ Therefore $\sum a_n$ diverges by comparison with the harmonic series.

Answer (score 2):

This is an old problem but I think a more detailed solution is worth having.

Suppose (1) $0<a_n\searrow0$ and (2) $\sum_na_n<\infty$, and
(3) $B:=\sup_n\Big(\frac{1}{a_{n+1}}-\frac{1}{a_n}\Big)<\infty$.
By (1) and (2) $\lim_\limits{n\rightarrow\infty} na_n=0$:
$$na_{2n}\leq a_{n+1}+\ldots + a_{2n}\xrightarrow{n\rightarrow\infty}0$$
and
$$(n+\frac12)a_{2n+1}\leq (n+1)a_{2n+1}\leq a_n+\ldots + a_{2n}\xrightarrow{n\rightarrow\infty}0$$
By (3),
\begin{align}
n\Big(1-\frac{a_{n+1}}{a_n}\Big)\leq B na_{n+1}\xrightarrow{n\rightarrow\infty}0
\end{align}
It follows from [Raabe's theorem](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/RaabesTest.html) that $\sum_na_n$ diverges, which contradicts (2). Hence, no such sequence $a_n$ exists.

Comment: Shouldn't it be "By (1) and (2) $ \lim_\limits{n\rightarrow\infty} n a_n=0 $"?